# Is it possible to do a switch statement on conditionals?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am looking to perform a `switch` statement on a conditional value, currently my statement looks like this:

```
switch (property)
  {
    case JToken token when (Schemas.IsNumericProperty(token)):
      return token.ToObject<int>();
    case JToken token when (Schemas.IsStringProperty(token)):
      return token.ToObject<string>();
    case JToken token when (Schemas.IsCollectionProperty(token)):
      return token.ToObject<string[]>();
    case JToken token when (Schemas.IsDependencyProperty(token)):
      return token.ToObject<KeyValue[]>();
    default:
      return property.ToObject<object>();
  }
```

However the property value is already a `JToken`, is there a way to clean this up to be short code? I know that I could just do a series of `if` statements, which might be a lot cleaner and more efficient?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the design concern is why is needed in the first place, who is sending random json at you, and why dont you know the structure before hand..  just saying... also id go with ifs (totally opinionated)

Comment: you could also use the Type field (JTokenType Enumeration) i guess

Comment: I suspect you need to restate the type. At least [this MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause) is doing the same. You can however simplify `JToken token` to `var _`

Comment: The Json is received from a front end that allows the specification of different fields for a user, the number and name of those fields is not known, only that they will fall into 4 categories. My program is designed to take those fields - along with associated weights (also provided by the front end) and run each field through a rules engine that compares them. So it's not entirely unstructured json, it's just quite flexible!

Comment: @Vlad Thanks, I think from that example you do have to. The general way with Pattern Matching is for objects and safely casting them to Types. This is what I am doing in another section of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be in search of like this

```
JToken jToken = JToken.Parse("your json");

switch (jToken.Type)
{
     case JTokenType.Integer:
        return jToken.ToObject<int>();

     case JTokenType.String:
        return jToken.ToObject<string>();

     case JTokenType.Array:
        return jToken.ToObject<string[]>();

     default:
        return jToken.ToObject<object>();
}
```

`JToken.Type` is of type `JTokenType` Enumeration that gives you to easily identify what the type of your token.

You can read more about [**`JTokenType Enumeration`**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm)

Comment: That would definitely solve some of the issues, but I need to be able to validate the Token via my validate methods, since I have multiple fields that will be JObjects, but different schemas.

Comment: that means its validate against `(Schemas.IsNumericProperty(token))`? and all others